# python functions: giving methods for arbitrary number of keywords

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've noticed that I'm getting in doubt more and more which tools of programming would be the most practical to use in the following situations. *It's needed to create a HUGE function which takes a list of optional amount of LISTS and does various PROCEDURES on each of them* It seems impractical (some cases even not possible) to use input like this:

```
def procedure1(array):...
def procedure2(array):...
...
def procedure_n(array):...
def common_procedure(array):...
def HUGE_function(*lists):
    #every list is of the form [(procedure1,...,procedure_n),x_1,x_2,x_3,...,x_m]
    common procedure([y[1:] for y in lists])
    for n in lists:
        for m in n[0]:
            m(n[1:]) #we call a function applied to m[1:]
```

First, as I've mentioned, it would seem not a formal style of programming to mix number and procedures in each argument of *lists. Plus, using an array as a first argument of each lists is not best choice. On the other hand, what if we want procedure1,procedure2,...,procedure_n to be default arguments? Then each n[0] (first argument) for n in lists needs to be used repeatedly - not the best way out too. 
When number of procedures is large, I would propose to interpret n[0] as *n[0] (a list of packed arguments) but I've never seen Python allowing to 2-dimensionally use *args in *args again.
Well, complicate... Any help?

Comment: I am not sure if this question should be asked here or in another forum/site of stack exchange, since it's more about the design of the program rather than a concrete problem...

Comment: why is using an array as a first argument not a good choice?

Comment: well, I want to use about 7 different lists and about 5 different procedures (procedure1, ... , procedure5) to do with them in my program. The mostly, these sequences of procedures should be set by default but it's not allowed in Python  to do it other way then manually. I would need to type these 5 default procedures 7 times repeatedly. What if an extra list is given? It is required to type a sequence of procedures (with mostly of them to be default) too. But then the meaning of using *list instead of lists (in words, argument packing) gets lost.